# Both public and intranet services on the same OpenShift cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

In my company we have few public websites and many internal webapps. Currently they are are running in different AWS security groups.

Is it possible to run both kind of services on the same OpenShift cluster and make sure internal services are not accessible from the Internet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional(?) way that is solved is through Internet-facing ELB/ALBs pointed to the NodePorts on the cluster. I personally haven't tried `Service` of `kind: LoadBalancer` since 1.2 to be able to speak to its functionality, but I do know kubernetes has a **lot** of users on AWS, so it's plausible it works fine by now.

You can also run your own Ingress Controller, several of which have support for ip white/black listing, authentication, SSL/TLS, all the fancy toys, if you'd prefer not to deal with the ELB headache.

If you're not already considering it, [Calico SDN](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.6/reference/architecture/) has support for in-cluster networking policies, so you could also apply an extra level of locked-down-ness to ensure no Internet app breaks out of its allowed network path; thus, security-groups moving down into the cluster.